# How do I run Nvidia Isaac on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: nvidia, software-installation

I know their [setup documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/isaac/isaac/doc/setup.html) states that it only supports 18.04, but is it still possible to run it on 20.04? When naively trying, the script that installs dependencies failed with:

```
E: Unable to locate package libvpx5
[ERROR] Failed to install packages - libvpx5 libtwolame-dev libtheora-bin libspeex1
```

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I found that lxd containers work for this situation, as they have [great support for nvidia passthrough](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/gpu-data-processing-inside-lxd#1-overview) (using an nvidia device inside of a container).

If you haven't done so already, first init `lxd` by typing:

```
lxd init
```

Create a new Ubuntu 18.04 container using with the `nvidia.runtime` config and add gpu to it:

```
lxc launch ubuntu:18.04 isaac -c nvidia.runtime=true
lxc config device add isaac gpu gpu
```

Push previously downloaded isaac sdk to container, log into container as `ubuntu` user, and install it:

```
lxc file push /<isaac folder>/isaac-sdk-<isaac version>.tar.xz isaac/tmp/i.txz
lxc exec isaac -- su ubuntu --login
mkdir isaac
cd isaac/
tar xf /tmp/i.txz 
cd engine/
./engine/build/scripts/install_dependencies.sh # it will take a very long time
```

This installed the dependencies as described. Afterwards I was able to build a sample app and run it:

```
cd
cd isaac/sdk
bazel build //apps/tutorials/ping  # this takes a long time first time around!
bazel run //apps/tutorials/ping
```

I was also able to bring up their "websight" visualization by opening http://10.24.150.210:3000/ on my desktop, where the ip is the one of the lxc container (run `ip addr` inside to find it).

To facilitate the development workflow, I also mapped a local folder on the host to the container and mapped the userids so I could edit from inside and outside of the container (primarily so I could use my favorite editor on the host):

```
mkdir ~/shared
lxc config device add isaac myshareddir disk path=/ubuntu/shared source=/home/`whoami`/shared
lxc config set isaac raw.idmap "both 1000 1000"
lxc restart isaac
```